# How do I "enable" a function based on a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a a template function:

```
template<class Route, bool enabled=true>
void addRoute() {
    std::cout << "Route added";
}
```

I want to disable the function if `enabled=false`. I know there is no way to disable calling of a function from parameters unless using macros. However, since this function will be called once through the lifetime of the program, I don't mind calling an empty function if enabled is set to false. So, I tried the first thing that came to mind:

```
template<class Route>
void addRoute<false>() { }
```

This failed, so I did some digging and found out that partial template specialization is not possible; I can create a partially specialized class with arguments and do the same thing.

Is there another way to do this problem or should I stick with creating a class with static function?

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you want to "disable" the function if you explicitly specify the second parameter? It's `true` by default and it's not deduced, so the only way to call this function is via

```
addRoute<RouteType, false>();
```

In that context, "disabled" could only mean it generates an error, right? If you want that, just add

```
static_assert( enabled, "Not enabled!" );
```

to the function's body as the first line. Or if you want to just "skip" the code inside, you can simply add

```
if( !enabled ) return;
```

as the first line. The optimizer will make sure that no superfluous code will be generated.

Comment: Wow! I feel really stupid now. How can I forget about `!enabled` :P thanks